# How to monitor Inserts for whole sharded cluster via web?

Tags: mongodb

I have installed and running MongoDB sharded cluster which consists of:

```
conf1.example.com
conf2.example.com
conf3.example.com
query1.example.com
query2.example.com
shard1.example.com
shard2.example.com
shard3.example.com
```

Is there any possibility to monitor **INSERTS** for whole cluster but not for each instance separately via **WEB interface**? I'm not MongoDB developer, so I need easy installation solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried http://mms.mongodb.com/?

Comment: Yes, but there is no possibility to monitor inserts. Maybe something else?

Comment: Are you trying to monitor the counters of inserts, or the actual insert queries? MMS Monitoring most definitely aggregates the history of opcounters which includes inserts, deletes, updates, queries, and commands. If you have a sharded cluster you can also see the activity across a cluster view (eg. inserts by shard combined on a single chart).